# Insert html tag before and after the text in kendo ui editor

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, editor

I want to insert an html tag when user type something on kendo UI Editor before and after the letter we have typed .I have tried the below code , But it's inserting tag after the text like below
[image]

Source code I have tried

```
function editor_keydown(e) {
            debugger;
            var myEditor = editor.data("kendoEditor")
            var storedRange = myEditor.getRange();
            myEditor.selectRange(storedRange);
            myEditor.exec("inserthtml", { value: "<insert></insert>" });
            //alert("keydown : keyCode=", e.keyCode);
        }
```

I am expecting something like this

```
<insert>a</insert>
```

Is there any way to achieve using javascript??

Comment: Did you try just simple concatenation "<insert>" + e + "</insert>"  ?